# JQuery onclick function to focus input

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I want a JQuery function that means if the user clicks on some text on the page it focuses an input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#header.search span').click(function(){
    $('#header.search input').focus();
});
});
```

That did not do anything. On Firebug nothing is registered.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: Show us your html, and what input do you want to give focus to ? The closest one ?

Comment: [It's working fine here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/Fee3u/).

Answer (score 27):

http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/LXngq/

```
<span>
    <br>
        Span
    <br>
    <input id="InputToFocus" type="text">
</span>

$('span').click(function(){
    $('#InputToFocus').focus();
});
```

Seems to be working fine, It is probably a problem with your selectors. Could you post the structure of your HTML surrounding the input?

Answer (score 20):

If you have `id` to the input element then you dont need javascript to do this. You can use `for` attribute with a `label` tag pointing to the input element id. Try this

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QZye6/)**

```
<label for="input1">Name</label>
<input id="input1" type="text" />
```

If you click on Name text the focus will be set into the input field.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( "input" ).focus(function() {
  $( this ).next( "span" ).css( "display", "inline" ).fadeOut( 1000 );
});
```

```css
span {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type="text"> <span>focus fire</span></p>
<p><input type="password"> <span>focus fire</span></p>
```

https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score -1):

I think $('#header.search input') returns a bunch of INPUTs, not just one, so JQuery may not know which one to focus. You'll need to decide which one to focus.

Comment: In that case the [last element would take the focus](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/fwvQ2/).

Comment: Ah, didn't know about JSFiddle. Thanks.